# What differences (if any) are there between Joomla sessions and php sessions?

Tags: cms, session

I've been wondering this for a while now.

What are the differences between Joomla sessions and php sessions? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JSession is based on the standard PHP session handling mechanism** but I would not say they are interchangeable, as Joomla is directly "talking" to JSession and not to the super global.

In backend you select a session handler (the default being the database) where Joomla will store session related informations, basically it's serializing the content of `$_SESSION` itself.

When a cookie is sent, no actual readable data is stored, just a session identifier.

It also provides a very simple, namespaced interface to store and retrieve data from the user session. Read an entire article about this on [ostraining](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/how-to-use-sessions-in-joomla/).

Comment: "it's not storing much data in the $_SESSION itself" - Are you sure? I think all the session data is still stored in the `$_SESSION` superglobal, it's just that Joomla creates a [custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and wraps the setting/getting of $_SESSION properties with its own methods. If the data is not in $_SESSION then Joomla is doing something very non-PHP like?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Retracted the part with "it's not storing much data in the $_SESSION itself" as it was not true.

Answer (score 3):

Joomla uses the PHP session functions to create its `JSession` object, but it provides wrapper functions and namespaces the session to keep the data segregated. If you dump the PHP superglobal `$_SESSION` you will see the Joomla session items.